# Python puts tabs in where none should be

Tags: python

Need help formatting my Python web scrape .  For whatever reason when I get the info I need it seems that the words have been tabbed out of place and not sure how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.canadianappliance.ca/Refrigerators-And-Fridges-3/Full-Size-Refrigerators-38/French-Door-Refrigerators-48/?per_page=all")

r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)


g_data = soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "product_link"})

for item in g_data:
    print (item.text)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *tabbed out of place*?

Comment: Sorry maybe indented would have been the correct word.  The first word that I retrieve is about maybe 40 characters to the right of the left margin.

Comment: `[item.text.strip() for item in g_data]` - is that what you want? All those tabs are in the original HTML ...

Comment: Do you mean `item.a.text.strip()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) providing the `strip` argument. Additionally, replace newlines with spaces:

```
g_data = soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "product_link"})
for item in g_data:
    print(item.get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", " "))
```

Prints:

```
Samsung - RF220NCTASR
Samsung - RF18HFENBSR
Samsung - RF23HCEDBSR
...
Haier - HRF15N3AGS
GE Profile - PWE23KMKES
```

Comment: OK, that almost worked.  the indents are gone but the formatting now places the words on two lines.  I need them on one line.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks